# Access a hiddenfield inside gridview using jquery and update it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Ive got a gridview in asp.net
One of the fields is a hiddenfield inside of the gridview:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                      <input type="hidden" value="0" id="hdnIsChanged" runat="server" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have a radiobuttonlist inside the grid view as well, with a jquery click event which is working...
Here is that event:

```
$("#MainContent_gvLineItems input[id*='rbAnswer']").click(function () {
                    var parentRow = $(this).parents('tr').eq(1) //used to get the row at index 1, parents('tr').length prints 3.  
                    //tr around the checkbox is index 2
                    //tr around row is index 1
                    //tr around header is index 0
                    //so we want to get a reference to index=1
                    var firstCell = parentRow.find('td:eq(0)'); //find the first cell
                    var p = $(this).parents("div[id='dMainAnswer']").find(".Answer:first"); //used to find the panel
                    var val = $(this).val();

                    switch (val) //check the value 
                    {
                        case 'No':
                            firstCell.css('background-color', 'red');
                            p.show();
                            break;
                        case 'Yes':
                            firstCell.css('background-color', 'green');
                            p.hide();
                            break;
                        case 'N/A':
                            firstCell.css('background-color', 'gray');
                            p.hide();
                            break;
                        default:
                            firstCell.css('background-color', 'transparent');
                            p.show();
                            break;
                    }
                });
```

This is all fine, but within this click event I want to access the hidden field `hdnIsChanged` how do I reference it?  I tried:

`alert($('input[id$=hdnAnswered').val());`

But it continues to say undefined...
I want to be able to access it in this click event and set a value to it using jquery.
Please remember it is inside a gridview so it appears for every row...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would assign a class to your hidden field and try to access it like this:

```
$(this).closest(".myClass");
```

Keep in mind that since this is a server control, the ID of that hidden field is most likely be prepended with a bunch of asp.net junk.  So instead of it rendering like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="hdnIsChanged" />
```

it will most likely be rendered like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="clt100_clt100_290420349823049823423_hdnIsChanged" />
```

Comment: i thought of this let me try and ill get back to you.

Comment: hmm i tried this `alert($(this).closest(".hChanged").val());` but it still says undefined...

Comment: Where is the radio button that you are clicking in relation to the hidden input?

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert($("#hdnIsChanged").val())`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you tried this

```
alert($('input[id$=hdnAnswered').val());
```

but now try this...You forgot to close square bracket

```
alert($('input[id$=hdnAnswered]').val());
```

And here is the code that may help you to get the value of hiddenfield of a particular row

```
  $("#MainContent_gvLineItems input[id*='rbAnswer']").click(function () {
                    var parentRow = $(this).parent('tr');
                    var hiddenField=parentRow.find('input[id$=hdnIsChanged]');
                    alert(hiddenField.val());
    });
```